# Cache based on Url Parameter in Asp.net MVC

Tags: caching, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have defined a route culture/Controller/action/id... my controller contains following action..

```
 [OutputCache(Duration=60*10)]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {*/do magic here/*}
```

is it possible to Cache contents based on Culture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [localization complete guide](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html) presents an example of how to achieve this using the `VaryByCustom` parameter. In global.asax you would override the `GetVaryByCustomString` method:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string value)
{
    if (value == "lang")
    {
        return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
    }
    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, value);
}
```

and then:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 60 * 10, VaryByParam = "none", VaryByCustom = "lang")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    /* do magic here */
    ...
}
```

Or if you want to rely solely on the culture route data parameter you could do this:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string value)
{
    if (value == "lang")
    {
        var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
        var culture = (string)routeData.Values["culture"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(culture))
        {
            return culture;
        }
    }
    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, value);
}
```